# NUnit not seeing configSource defined connection strings when run from command line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jenkins, nunit, nunit-console

I have a problem with running automated tests on my Jenkins build server since I moved the connection strings from my config files to searate files using  `<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>`

When I open the project from the Jenkins workspace **in VS2013** and run the tests, **everything works fine**. When I try running the tests as part of the build job with the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" Path\To\Project\ProjectName.Tests.csproj /xml=TestResults.xml
```

I get errors in the console saying:

```
Test Error : ProjectName.Tests.TestClass.TestIfSomethingWorks
   System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'ConnectionStringName' could be found in the application config file.
```

Of course, both the `app.config` file and the `connectionStrings.config` file are in the root folder of the test project AND the projects in the solution that use these connection strings.

Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that `nunit-console.exe` is able to find your test assembly when you point it to the csproj file, but it's unable to locate the configuration file as it's running in a different working directory. You should be able to fix the issue by pointing NUnit to your test assembly DLL. Something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" Path\To\Project\ProjectName.Tests\bin\Debug\ProjectName.Tests.dll /xml=TestResults.xml
```

Give that a go, and good luck!